# How to avoid and fix performance problems in firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am facing some **performence** problems with my **firefox extension**. I just started developing
with firefox and have really view code for now.

For now I just perform some form validation which sometimes freezses the the whole form.

I am curious about your advice. What **programming techniques** enhance the performance?

**Update:** it seems that following code causes the extension to freeze for 1-2 sec. when the timer reaches 5000.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    notify.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: In _normal_ js programmers usually write: `notify.style.display = "none";`

Comment: What kirilloid said will work just as well in an extension as it would on a web page. It may even be slightly faster, though I don't see any reason why your current code would take more than a second to execute. Are you absolutely sure that's the code that's freezing the browser?

Comment: Depending on which notifications/events you have on the page it's possible that some extensive DOM processing is done upon this change. Try putting this code in some click event so you can click on a button and see if upon click you get the same freeze behaviour.

Comment: well, I have a predefined label, when the user clicks on the send button some validation is performed (just some length and regex checking) and as a result I change the value attribute of the label to inform the user so nothing extensive there...maybe there are some other stuff on my computer that slow things down. But my question was more general. So just code as it would be a webpage?

Comment: post this as an answer if you want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as XUL development goes, most of it is just like developing a web page (with a bit extended API).